# Read JSON File From Database in Anuglar

Tags: json, angular, typescript, file, read-write

Is there anyway to read a JSON file from data base. Make some changes and save it back to database in Angular. I had googled it always shows the reading of JSON file from Asset Folder which is not my requirement.

I was expecting to read a file from database store it in a variable and make some changes and store it back to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON, JavaScript Object Notation, is the standard representation of object within web apps. What this means is that retrieving your JSON from the database can be saved to a variable in your Angular app. Then you can make your changes and send an update command.

This is demonstrated in [a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-apxnv6?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with explicit functions to do database reads and writes which you will have to update.

Additionally, if the database stores the JSON as a serialized string, you will have to encode/decode using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` on the variable representing the server data.